# Configuring puppet third party modules

Tags: puppet

I am creating masterless provisioning with Puppet.  I have installed a third party module alongside with my custom module called **my_module**:

```
puppet module install maestrodev/rvm
```

Now in my modulepath I've got the following:

```
my_module
rvm
some_dependencies
```

After that it gets interesting.  I want to configure my module as per its [PuppetForge Documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/rvm).

The question is where do I put all that newly created configuration?

In my_module/tests/init.pp file?  In some kind of overriding module?

Please forgive me for my noob question, but I've searched the documentation for this particular scenario pretty hard and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to create set of pp files, as given in the documentation, it's suggested that you put them all together in a single directory (named "manifest" by convention) so that when you run the puppet "apply" command on the directory, puppet will parse all the pp files in alphabetical order and execute them all together

Ex: puppet apply /etc/.../puppet/manifests

For execution of a single file:

puppet apply /etc/.../puppet/manifests/JohnDoe.pp

Reference:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_manifest.html